# Removing View from getView

Tags: android-layout, android

I'm trying to hide a button inside getView method of an Adapter. Unfortunately, I can't do it.

```
private class AppListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Info> {
        public AppListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Info> apps) {
            super(activity, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, apps);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // if we weren't given a view, inflate one
            if (null == convertView) {
                convertView = getLayoutInflater()
                        .inflate(R.layout.activity_apps, null);
            }
            btnUninstall = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.uninstallButton);
            btnUninstall.setOnClickListener(
                    new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                             btnUninstall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        }
                    }
            );
            return convertView;
        }

    }
```

Any help shall be appreciated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing this line

```
btnUninstall.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

To this

```
v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
```

Comment: v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); works but the button is in every row item...and it's removing it at every subsequent row...strange...

Comment: What exactly do u mean, it hides all buttons ?

Answer (score 1):

That's because in the adapter android passes the same view over and over again (recycling), try to set the visibility of the button to visible every time.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the code and it works fine for me.!
Hey quick question though, have you declared your btnUninstall anywhere? 
I cannot see it anywhere in the code you have provided, thats all.

```
     Button btnUninstall;
```